# Table of width 100% is not working and table doesn't fit the chrome browser window size

Tags: html, css, html-table

Table of `width: 100%` is not working in Chrome How to fit the entire table to the chrome browser window size. Multiple tables inside a table are causing the table to become larger.

I have multiple Tables within a table as shown below :

```
 <table style="width:100%">

        <tr>
            <td>
             <label> Version </label>
            </td>

            <td ng-repeat="----" >

                 <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-style:hidden;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="{{List.length}}" > 
                            {{abc}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >

                       <span ng-init="getUnique(---)">
                        <td ng-repeat="--">
                           {{abc}}    
                        </td>                     
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <span ng-init="getUnique(---)">
                        <td ng-repeat="--" >
                                  <table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                        <tr>
                                                 <td ng-repeat="--" >
                                                    {{abc}}
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                          </td>  
                    </tr>

                 </table>         
            </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: can you give the full code? I doubt that an outside class that make the width not 100%

Comment: if with `width: 100%;` you are trying to get it 100% width of your screen, try `width: 100vw;` which does exactly that (VW = View Width, so then your saying 100% of my view width)

Comment: @Jeremy : I tried with width: 100vw; : But it did not work

Comment: The code in your question does not demonstrate the problem. Can you create a [mcve]? Also, in a table where the content is wider than 100%, what exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: @JuggleJack : I have removed the class references. But still, the table width is not working as expected

Comment: @MrLister : The table is beyond the screen size.As of now, i should scroll the see the entire table. So, I want my table to fit the window size.

Comment: But what should happen with the content? With a table like in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/jen3dw6e/4/), how should the result look? Should everything be displayed in the window? How?

Comment: I tried your code in https://jsfiddle.net/fkvxpsou/ and is full 100%. So, if you want further assistance, I hope you can give full code, so we can help you debugging the problem.

Comment: @MrLister : But the table content is not large in my case. It's like this :https://docs.google.com/document/d/17drVMk9CIA900scZCWZLR4Xe4WSnqC4whDcv_qb7Nho/edit

Comment: @NavyaNagaraj Again, can you create  a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Your code here _does not_ produce the table shown on the Google page.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do is make the scroll bar.

You can wrap by div and set `overflow: scroll`

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
  <table style="width:100%">
```

see the result https://jsfiddle.net/jen3dw6e/9/

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this URL you will got resolution.

```
` https://jsfiddle.net/imraushanshrivastva/ubp466yf/`
```